# How to integrate Cloudinary with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I want users to upload photos for their profile and I want to display their photo on the navbar when they're logged in.

These are the instructions for the lepozepo:cloudinary package (I am open to other alternatives):

Step 1

SERVER

```
Cloudinary.config
    cloud_name: 'cloud_name'
    api_key: '1237419'
    api_secret: 'asdf24adsfjk'
```

CLIENT

```
$.cloudinary.config
    cloud_name:"cloud_name"
```

Step 2

Wire up your input[type="file"]. CLIENT SIDE.

```
Template.yourtemplate.events
    "change input[type='file']": (e) ->
        files = e.currentTarget.files

        Cloudinary.upload files,
            folder:"secret" # optional parameters described in http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#remote_upload
            (err,res) -> #optional callback, you can catch with the Cloudinary collection as well
                console.log "Upload Error: #{err}"
                console.log "Upload Result: #{res}"
```

For each of the steps, I'm not sure where to place the code. For example, I don't know where I should put Cloudinary.config. Where at on the server?

```
Title
client
  -helpers
    config.js
  -stylesheets
  -templates
    profile
      profile.html
      profile.js
  -main.html
  -main.js
lib
  -collections


server
  -config
    *cloudinary.js
  -fixtures.js
  -publications.js
```

cloudinary.js

```
Cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: '***',
  api_key: '***',
  api_secret: '***'
});
```

profile.html

```
<template name="profile">
  <div>
    <form>
     <input type="file" id="userimage" name="userimage"/>
     <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

profile.js

```
Template.profile.events({
  // Submit signup form event
  'submit form': function(e, t){
      // Prevent default actions
      e.preventDefault();

  var file = $('#userimage')[0].files[0];
  console.log(file)
  Cloudinary.upload(file, function(err, res) {
        console.log("Upload Error: " + err);
        console.log("Upload Result: " + res);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks life coffeescript

Comment: Okay, thanks. Any ideas on how to set everything up with Meteor?

Comment: I don't use meteor, but conceptually it's a similar process between different types of apps. On the server you have to configure your keys, and on the front-end you make API calls to your server (which interact with cloudinary). The last part (step 2 in your question) just adds an event listener to the `onchange` of file inputs, telling them to automatically upload to cloudinary.

Comment: place that anywhere under the server folder such as `server/configs/cloudinary.coffee`, same for the client ones. Just make sure you end with a "coffee" extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let me help you.

I assume that you project structure is something like:

```
  /main
    /client
      client.js
    /server
      server.js
```

Ok, lepozepo:cloudinary is written in coffescript but you can use it with vanilla javascript, so with the the folder structure showed above, you can use the following code:

```
client.js
$.cloudinary.config({
cloud_name: "yourname"
});

sometemplateveent({
  .... some event code
  Cloudinary.upload(files,{}, function(err, img) {
   ... do something when uploaded
  });

});
```

and then.

```
server.js

Cloudinary.config({
 cloud_name: 'yourname',
 api_key: 'somekey',
 api_secret: 'someapisecret'
});
```

If you need help with the submit event + upload the image you can read this post: [Meteor: Cloudinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919613/meteor-cloudinary)

Comment: I don't have a client.js or server.js file. Should I add these? I currently have  under my client folder: helpers, stylesheets, templates, main.html, main.js

Comment: add the client code in main.js. You need the server folder with server.js or main.js it does not matter the name, just the folder.

Comment: Since I want them to upload a photo on their profile page, should I add the client code in profile.js instead (this along with profile.html is included in my templates folder)?

Comment: I added the server code that you wrote in client/config/cloudinary.js ... I hope this is okay.

Comment: let me now if it work, do not forget to check the question I linked. **UPDATE:** I edited my answer now you can check the question

Comment: I receive an error message: ReferenceError: Cloudinary is not defined
    at app/server/config/cloudinary.js:1:36 ... Where should I define it? And what do I define?

Comment: can you edit your question with your folder structure and the cloudinary code that you are using ? I need more information to help you :) **PD:** before update your question try to add the official coffescript package    meteor add coffeescript

Comment: Somehow the package didn't install, so I redid it and now there isn't an error.

Comment: @JonRoby you need to use the code inside client.js (the one in my answer) put it in main.js or create a cloudinary.js file in the client folder. this one : $.cloudinary.config({
cloud_name: "yourname"
});

Comment: Yes, I have added it to main.js. It seems that it is working. Now I just have to show it.

Comment: check your cloudinary dashboard :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87316/discussion-between-jon-roby-and-jose-osorio).